# Fix missing duration in audio file

Tags: audio, webm

I'm creating webm files via recording in the browser. However, the duration of the file isn't in the final file due to the nature of how the sound is captured (the recording is cut off at an arbritrary time when some other process ends).

I can get the correct duration by running:

```
$ ffmpeg -i filename.webm -f null -
$ [snip] size=N/A time=00:00:02.39 bitrate=N/A
```

Is there a way to fix the missing duration? i.e. inserting the time metadata back into the file without transcoding (or otherwise losing quality).